# Store both original and filtered image under the same folder - LiipImagineBundle

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle

I am using LiipImagineBundle to create a filtered image from an uploaded image. The current configuration of the bundle is:

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
       default:
          web_path: ~

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        my_filter:
            filters:
                relative_resize: { heighten: 66 }
```

My Goal is to create a directory structure like:

`web_root\{subdirectory}\{type}_{filename_md5_hash}.jpeg`

The type is either `s` for small image or `o` for original size. The subdirectory is created from upload date.

The problem is that LiipImagineBundle stores the filtered images in `web_root\my_filter\{subdirecory}\{type}_{filename_md5_hash}.jpeg`.

How can I omit the `my_filter` part of the url? I need each uploaded image and its filtered to be stored on the same final folder.

I am not an expert and I did a lot of research to no avail. The configuration allows to change the web path of cache either for the whole filters or for individual filters but the filter name always apears in the final url.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the services provided with LiipImagineBundle to have more control on the filtering process. In other words, instead of getting `liip_imagine.controller` service inside controller, I used the "underlying" services : `liip_imagine.data.manager`, `liip_imagine.filter.manager` and `liip_imagine.cache.manager`.

In my special situation, I omitted also the use of `liip_imagine.cache.manager` because I finally decided to store the filtered images in the same directory as the original images. So cache is not involved (neither in configuration nor in direcrory strucure). So everything is stored now in `web\images`

```
    $small_path= 's_'. $image_file->getClientOriginalName();


    $filter = 'my_filter';
    $config= array( 'widen' => 960) ;

    $path = $image->getWebPath();

    $container = $this->container;                                 
    $dataManager = $container->get('liip_imagine.data.manager');
    $filterManager = $container->get('liip_imagine.filter.manager');

    $binary = $dataManager->find($filter, $path);

    $filteredBinary =  $filterManager->applyFilter( $binary, $filter, array(
                           'filters' => array(
                               'relative_resize' =>  $config
                            )
                        ));

    $small_path = str_replace("subdirectory/","subdirectory/s_",'subdirectory/'.$small_path );
    $s = $sBinary->getContent();                               

    $f = fopen($smallPath, 'w');                                 
    fwrite($f, $s );                                            
    fclose($f);
```

Of course, this invloves a change in configuration:

```
    my_filter:
        filters:
            relative_resize: []
```

In fact, I can now use dynamically any configuration of `relative_resize` built-in filter.
Thank you for your time. and I hope I receive feedback regarding this approach.

Comment: Since you don't use cache at all with this solution, you might have performance issues in the long run. And I don't see why you save the file into your subdirectory, given you always generate the filtered file at runtime and never use the cached one. But besides that, I agree this works. This is less optimal and clean than what I suggested, but it does the job.

Comment: @Terenoth, thank you for your time sir. I honneslty don't understand why might `I have performance issues in the long run`. I don't generate filtered file at runtime. What I do is create filtered image  while uploading the file (inside uploadAction in controller) . I then `cache` it in a different folder than liipImagineBundle default  folder. Your explanations are hightly appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I thought your code was a display action, not an upload action, my bad. In that case, no performance problems indeed. I guess the only argument one could do is that you actually don't need LiipImagineBundle, but only Imagine itself, since you don't really use the cache and filter features of LiipImagine. You could just get the uploaded binary, apply Imagine functions to it, and then save your new File, without even calling `liip_imagine.data.manager` and `liip_imagine.filter.manager`. But as long as things work, you're good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want requires you to create a custom `CacheResolver` (implementing `Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\Resolver\ResolverInterface`). It's not an easy task at first, but it's the only way to have such a particular use case.

Then, register your custom `CacheResolver` as a service with the tag `liip_imagine.cache.resolver`, give your tag a `resolver` attribute with the name of your choice (e.g. `<tag name="liip_imagine.cache.resolver" resolver="same_folder" />`), and use this resolver in your config.yml

```
liip_imagine:
    filter_sets:
        FILTER_NAME:
            cache: same_folder
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, but while doing, I followed another approach I gave as answer. Any remarks are hightly appreciated.